# Linking GA4 to BigQuery not working after 24 hours

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to link a recently-created Google Analytics GA4 data stream to a BigQuery account. I've checked every tutorial I can find and I've set up everything correctly as far as I can tell. However, more than 24 hours later, there is no data connection. I can't find any information on how to debug this - does anybody have any ideas?

Below are pictures showing what I've set up. The BigQuery account is paid, not sandbox.

GA4 report showing there is some data in Google Analytics:

[image]

GA4 link to BigQuery:

[image]

BigQuery service account:

[image]

BigQuery project with no data flowing:

[image]

I have blanked out names but I only have one BigQuery project so I've definitely linked GA4 to the correct one.

There is only one data stream, web, and it is selected in the link.

Can anyone think of any other configuration or setting which I might need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two days later and BigQuery has decided to connect to GA4. I changed nothing. It seems that it can take three or four days to connect after you've set everything up, and there's no way to get any feedback while waiting.

Comment: As the GA4 account had only just been set up, and Google Analytics reports lag a couple of days behind, that may be the reason for the delay - no GA4 reports had been generated.

Comment: So glad found this post. Gonna wait a few more days, but noticed that the data still doesn't show even after enabling streaming

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), the possible reason for the delay is the **changes on the property timezone** as the export takes `24-hour snapshot` of the property. The timezone can affect the export window and might shorten or lengthen the process.

You can try and choose to enable the `streaming export` to have a **continuous export of data** rather than `daily export` as it only performs **once a day**, to gather the data faster than expected.

It is also recommended to have an `editor role` to your project or service account when exporting the data.

Comment: Thanks. I did choose "streaming" as well as "daily" and the doc you linked to recommends the minimum required role which is "BigQuery user", so I think I did have the best possible setup. And the doc says you should see data within 24 hours; but it took at least three days.